# What is logic behind Math.max method?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function max that will return max value number.

I managed so far:

```
function max() {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i in arguments) {
        arr.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b - a;
    });
    return arr[0];
}
var test = max(30, 20, 50, 40, 100, 150, 5, 230);
var test2 = Math.max(30, 20, 50, 40, 100, 150, 5, 230);
```

Both returns 230;

But I don't want to use in-built functionality i.e Math.max. Also no prototype. So how I can do this?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: So what is wrong with your current `max` implementation? What does "no prototype" mean in this case?

Comment: You can use selection method to get the max from an array'

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Didn’t you already do it? Your function works and uses neither `Math.max` nor prototypes. What is your question?

Comment: "*I don't want to use in-built functionality*" why would you? It's only a native function that's a lot faster compared to a slow custom function. /s

Comment: `for (var i in arguments) {
        arr.push(arguments[i]);
    }` WHY ? arguments is an array...

Comment: @Virus721: **no, it's not**. It's an object that happens to have a `length` property.

Comment: Yeah anyway, this code is terribly bad. There is no need to use a sorting algorithm calling a callback for each element, you simply have to store the first element, and for each other elements, check if it is greater/smaller and update the max/min when it is.

Comment: I know max method is there. I just exploring other ways of doing it.    http://jsperf.com/math-vs-logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 function max(arr)   
 {
    var largest;
    if(arr.length>0)
    largest=arr[0];
    else 
    largest = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
      if(arr[i]>largest)
      largest = arr[i];
    }
    return largest;
 }
```

Comment: Starting at `arr[0]` is fine if you know that the array has at least one element; you could even skip the first element then by starting at `i = 1`.

Comment: @shadow Thanks. But how to do this using function?

Comment: Pass your array as an argument to function max

Answer (score 0):

Simple really. This can be done in `O(n)` time by cycling through the `array` once.

In Pseudocode:

```
number := first item in list.
for each item in the list
    if(number < item)
        number := item.
    end if
end for

print("Max is: " + number).
```

Although, your method seems to work fine.